# can anyone please explain what is meaning of band.conf , mesh.conf and pdos.conf in phonon calculation?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, phonopy, phonon-density-of-state, phonon-dispersion

Can anyone please explain, what is the physical meaning of band.conf, mesh.conf and pdos.conf in phonon calculation?
if it is possible please explain about tags used in it.

Comment: This is a very broad question, have you looked at the documentation online? For example, http://grandcentral.apam.columbia.edu:5555/documentation/phonopy/phonopy.html ; which bits are you confused by?

Comment: thank you for the link. My confusion is regarding the tags used in band and mesh files. @PhilHasnip

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP provides further clarification.